# Python `pip` on Windows - SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate

I'm working with Windows and since two days ago, I'm getting the following error:

```
    ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='f
iles.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/da/6
d/1235da14daddaa6e47f74ba0c255358f0ce7a6ee05da8bf8eb49161aa6b5/pandas-1.5.3-cp31
1-cp311-win_amd64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CER
TIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl
.c:992)')))
```

I get the error working with the python installed on my pc also into the different virtual environments. I tried it on Python 3.10 and 3.9 and both get it.

To solve it I tried the following solutions but neither of them worked:

> This error occurs when the SSL certificate verification fails during a package installation using pip in Python on a Windows system. To fix this error, you can follow the steps given below:
>
> Download the cacert.pem file from the official cURL website (https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) and save it in a suitable location on your computer.
>
> Set the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable to the path of the "cacert.pem" file. You can do this by opening the Command Prompt and running the following command:
>
> ```
> setx SSL_CERT_FILE "C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
> ```
>
> Make sure to replace C:\path\to\cacert.pem with the actual path where you saved the "cacert.pem" file.
>
> Close and reopen the Command Prompt to ensure that the environment variable is set correctly.
>
> Try running the pip install command again.
>
> This should resolve the error and allow you to install packages using pip on your Windows system.

> Upgrade pip to the latest version using the following command:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
> ```
>
> Add the --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org option to your pip install command to instruct pip to trust the SSL certificates of these domains. For example:
>
> ```
> pip install <package-name> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
> ```
>
> If the above steps did not work, you can try updating the certifi package using the following command:
>
> ```
> pip install --upgrade certifi
> ```
>
> This will update the CA certificates that are used by Python to verify SSL connections.
>
> If you are still facing the issue, you can try disabling SSL verification by adding the `--trusted-host` and `--no-verify options` to your pip install command:
>
> ```
> pip install <package-name> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-verify
> ```
>
> However, this is not recommended as it can pose a security risk.

As I mentioned, neither solution fixed the error. What is wrong with the SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Just try `pip install <package-name> --trusted-host pypi.org` without the part `--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`. For me, it worked.

Comment: I tried it too but shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

I saw you're trying to install pandas 1.5.3. If you want, download and install the pandas package by downloading the file from PyPI website (https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files) and then install it using pip like :

`pip install /path/to/pandas-1.5.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: It's just an example with pandas but happens with any package, how do I find a permanent solution?